# how to change git commit message content type?

Tags: git

I want to include one hyper link in my git committed message. By using hooks wrote a script which will add the link to text i needed. But problem here is git committed message is updating as text instead of html message. In UI it showing whole URL instead of anchor. Is there any way that i can get anchor instead of whole URL in git page

ABC-123 is the keyword i am adding the anchor tag which will redirect it to JIRA Id. 
I am committing the git message using this keyword and inject URL using the hooks(Ex URL:https://*****.jira.net/ABC-123).

In git it coming like "https://*****.jira.net/ABC-123 ABC-123 update in pom.xml" instead of "ABC-123 update in pom.xml"

Comment: What UI are you using?

Comment: if you are using jira, simply typing the issue name without any links will create a link to the task automatically in the bitbucket repo

Comment: It's usually the git UI, e.g. Gitlab, which recognizes ticket IDs, e.g. Jira, and converts them to links when rendering the commit message in HTML.

Comment: i am using jira. But i looking for a way to do it in github.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jira, then you just need to type the Jira task name in the commit somewhere and the Bitbucket UI will link that to your Jira issue.

Ex:

```
This is a super cool fix

Implements TASK-1234
```

And then you'll have a hyperlink to the issue.

If you are using GitHub, then you can do something similar. `#XYZ` is the syntax and you can use it like this

```
This is another super cool fix in GitHub

Implements #1234
```

I do not believe that you can cross-reference in such an elegant way issues from one platform to another. In that case you just post the full link in the commit and then you copy/paste it in the browser.

Comment: Looking for an option in git where i can show a link which redirects it to jira. And i dont want to show full URL in browser i want it look like an anchor tag

Comment: If you are using Jira, then my answer will help. Otherwise, git does not have an option to embed and parse links in its commits without any external UI (as provided by Github or Jira or Gitlab)

Comment: by taking help of git hooks i am able to embed the URL in git commit but problem is while parsing the URL its not showing it as expected